Equation of motion of a 1D chain of particles connected with a spring (Euler-Lagrange)
Can someone help me understand how the result of the euler lagrange for the following system is what I am about to write:
If the system is an 1D chain of objects connected with springs. Then the lagrangian can be written: $$L=a\sum_i\left(\frac{m}{2}\frac{\dot q_i^2}{a} - \frac{ka}{2}\frac{(q_{i+1}-q_i)^2}{a^2}\right)$$ where a is the spacing between two points.
The euler lagrange gives:
$$\frac{m}{a}\frac{d}{dt}\dot q_i -ka \frac{(q_{i+1}-q_i)}{a^2}+ ka \frac{(q_{i}-q_{i-1})}{a^2}$$
where does the term $ka \frac{(q_{i}-q_{i-1})}{a^2}$ comes from?

Hint: Take i=7 in your E-L equation. The potential has two terms involving $q_7$, namely one involving $(q_8-q_7)^2$, and one involving $(q_7-q_6)^2$. Can you take it from there?

The potential was given as $V=\frac{k}{2}\sum_i (q_{i+1}-q_i)^2$, where $q_{i+1}$ is the displacement of the point at position $i+1$ and $q_i$ the displacement of point at position $i$ from equalibrium. So even the definition of potential is confusing, since it is essentially calculating something, using the difference of displacements.

So you have the Lagrangian
$$L=a\sum_i\left(\frac{m}{2}\frac{\dot q_i^2}{a} 
- \frac{ka}{2}\frac{(q_{i+1}-q_i)^2}{a^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
The Euler-Lagrangian equations for this are:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right)
=\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} \tag{2}$$
Notice that I used another index $j$ here
to avoid confusion with summation index $i$ in (1).
Inserting (1) into (2) gives
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(a\sum_i\left(m\frac{\dot{q}_i}{a}\frac{\partial \dot{q}_i}{\partial \dot{q}_j} \right)\right)
=\sum_i \left(-ka\frac{q_{i+1}-q_i}{a^2}
\left(\frac{\partial q_{i+1}}{\partial q_j}-\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial q_j}\right)\right)
\tag{3}$$
Now notice that the partial derivatives occurring in (3)
are just Kronecker deltas.
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(a\sum_i\left(m\frac{\dot{q}_i}{a}\delta_{i,j} \right)\right)
=\sum_i \left(-ka\frac{q_{i+1}-q_i}{a^2}
\left(\delta_{i+1,j}-\delta_{i,j}\right)\right)
\tag{4}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(a\sum_i\left(m\frac{\dot{q}_i}{a}\delta_{i,j} \right)\right)
=-\sum_i \left(ka\frac{q_{i+1}-q_i}{a^2}\delta_{i+1,j}\right)
+\sum_i \left(ka\frac{q_{i+1}-q_i}{a^2}\delta_{i,j}\right)
\tag{5}$$
Now do the summations over $i$, and notice that
in every sum only one term will survive.
I hope you will be able to finish the calculation from here.

I see. Because the point at position $i-1$ is related to $i$ and point $i+1$ to $i$. So when you differentiate w.r.t $q_i$ only those two components survive. Is my understanding correct?
